# Apache web server with symfony application

Tags: php, apache, symfony, mariadb, orangehrm

I have apache web server with symfony application ([OrangeHRM](https://www.orangehrm.com/OpenSource.php) open source edition) in it and MariaDB 10.
Here is my problem:

1. Open my browser.
2. Enter the url for the login page of the server.
3. Provide credentials.
4. The main dashboard is displayed.
5. When I click somewhere to open other page I have to wait two minutes in order to page to load.
6. After that each other page load is done properly (for a second).

On step five when I tried to debug the problem I used Firebug in order to check what is happening, so when I click somewhere already authentication in the application the received messages from the server stops and after 2 minutes waiting like a bulk query I got a lot of messages received.

I checked the DB and it seems that there are not slow queries. Also the DB itself it really really small, because this is quit new installation and this behavior is noticeable from the beginning.

Is there a way I can debug or I can check what could be the root cause of this problem?

Anyone else has similar problem with apache server and symfony application in it?

Comment: Is it an installation on a server or in local?

Comment: "No slow queries"?  Probably you have `long_query_time` set the default of 10 (seconds).  Change it to 1.

Comment: @Veve No, this is not a local installation. This is a Virtual Machine. I am browsing from my laptop.

Comment: @RickJames  I did what you suggested, but there is no change in the behavior.

Comment: @Veve My laptop is running on Windows 10, and the VM is running on CentOS 6.8.

Comment: @Veve, not sure what you are suggesting. The web server with the sympfony itself is running on a CentOS virtual system. I just connect from my laptop (Windows 10) to the web server via my browser.

Yesterday I did a test env where I installed the same software but on XAMP server (CentOS 6.8 VM) as the vendor suggests in its site. I cannot see this delay in my browser. after the login I can browse via all menus without any delays...

Comment: Ok my bad, misunderstood, will delete my comments.

Comment: Decreasing `long_query_time` -- I'm not expecting behavior change, rather something to show up in the slowlog.

Comment: How big is your VM?  What are the MySQL settings?  It could be that it is so cramped for RAM that it is frantically swapping.

Comment: @RickJames I think that it is not based on the hardware parameters of the VM. However it has 4 GB RAM and 3 of them are free. Also it has 1 CPU, but most of the time it is not loaded more than 1%. After I enabled this long_query_time when I check for slow queries, mysql do not report any.

Comment: None are in the log?  Crank it down to "0" for a while.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames I made the long_query_time down to 0 and I still do not have any slow queries: 
Threads: 1  Questions: 620  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 47  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 40  Queries per second avg: 0.473
Now about the innodb_buffer_pool_size variable. It has this value: 134217728, and if I am not mistaking this is 128MB. Should it be different? Please keep in mind that this is very small DB so far.

Comment: Is the slowlog turned on?  Is it set to `FILE` or `TABLE`?  Is there anything in that file/table?

Comment: Something is taking 2 minutes; either it is some very slow queries or some very inefficient code.  Perhaps you can show us the code for the page.

Comment: @RickJames OK, sorry, but the slow query wasn't configured properly the previous time. Now it logs everything to a file (I am still using long_query_time=0) and I got this in the mysql:Threads: 1  Questions: 1003  Slow queries: 964  Opens: 85  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 78  Queries per second avg: 1.928...... However when I used long_query_time=1 I got this: Threads: 1  Questions: 277  Slow queries: 23  Opens: 64  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 57  Queries per second avg: 1.610... I can show you the code of the index.php, because its the page that browses right after the first login.

Comment: From the log file I can see most of the queries are taking less than this: Query_time: 0.001464.

Comment: Use `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to summarize the slowlog and list the 'worst' first.

Comment: @RickJames This is very cool toll. Thanks for it. It summarized the data as you said, but I still cannot find mysql query that took more that 0.01second.... This is the first raw of the summary:
Count: 1  Time=0.01s (0s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=162.0 (162), Rows_examined=810.0 (810), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), orangehrm[orangehrm]@localhost

Comment: I often instrument my web pages with echos of `microtime(true)` to discover where it is spending the most time.  This will cover both mysql and php sluggishnesses.  Then I focus on the slow chunk of code.

Comment: Oh...  Is that 0.1sec query being executed a zillion times in a loop?

Comment: As I can see from the log each time new query has been executed. There are no zillion times loops in this log. I am not sure what I need to do with this "microtime(true)". When I use the Firebug and check the queries that are taking place in the log below, I can see that nothing happens until 2 min wait period. After that like a bulk function - every thing is executed.

Comment: @RickJames do you have any other suggestions? :)